# plugin seems to be undefined in cordova..!

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am currently working on cordova/phonegap,i have installed refreshgallary plugin from 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-refresh-gallery' but i am not getting it in 'window' object, it seems to be undefined every time.
under plugin www folder pluginRefresgGallary.js file code look like below(code is altered):-

```
cordova.define("Plugins/RefreshGalleryPlugin/", function (require, exports, module) {

var exec = require('cordova/exec');
// Plugin Refresh Gallery - Android

var RefreshMedia = function() {
};

RefreshMedia.prototype.refresh = function(url) {
    exec(success, error, "PluginRefreshGallery", "refresh", [url]);
};

var success = function(success){
    //alert("Success");
},

error = function(error){
    //alert("Error");
};

window.refreshMedia = new RefreshMedia();
module.exports = refreshMedia;
})
```

before this i was getting an error called module isn't defined and i 'd defined module like above code error is solved but i'm not getting refreshGallry plugin into windows object.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

This error happens sometimes when debugging, just dont care.

As I see in the plugin docs, it doesn't work into window object. Just call it `refreshMedia` into your javascript.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but when i am calling it directly it seems to be undefined..